# If $a_n / n \to L$ does $\sum_{k = 1}^{a_n} \frac{k}{(n - k)^2}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative intergers such that $a_n < n$ and $a_n / n \to L \in \mathbb{R}$. Does $b_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{a_n} \frac{k}{(n - k)^2}$ converges?

It is quite easy to show that $\{b_n\}$ is a bounded sequence. I tried to show monotonicity and adapt Abel's test for this case. Neither strategy worked.

Comment: If $a_n\geq n$, then you divide by $0$ so $b_n$ is undefined.

Comment: True, I always forget a hp.

Comment: Hint: $$\frac k{(n-k)^2}=\frac{1}{n}\dfrac{\frac kn}{\left(1-\frac kn\right)^2}$$

Comment: $a_n<n$ is insufficient; you need $L<1$.